# How to align input element in the middle of div?

Tags: html, css

For below html code,

```css
.shoppingform {
  width: 400px;
  height: 800px;
  background: #7CB9E8;
  /* url(some img)*/
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.customername {
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: black;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 10px 2px 5px 5px;
  background: #B284BE;
  width: 90%;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.customername {
  height: 5%;
}
.customername {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.shoppingform > div > input {
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 60%;
}
.formlabel {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<form class="shoppingform" action="someaction.php" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Step1: Your details
  <br>
  <div class="customername">
    <label class="formlabel">Name:</label>
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</form>
```

There are multiple `div` elements(like `customername`), which above code does not have,to make question simple.

`label` and `input` text are towards top side of the `div` container.

How do I vertically align the `label` and `input` text in the middle of the `div` container? To add, there are multiple `div` elements in the form.

Comment: give your .customername element a margin of auto.

Comment: You want vertical alignment, not horizontal right?

Comment: @AtheistP3ace yes vertical alignment

Comment: you mean align vertically? label and input verticaled aligned inside the "customerme" or "customerme" div aligned vertically from "shppingform?. Right atm it's not clear at all what you want.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8xdkhoee/

Play with this

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez  Only label and input verticaled aligned inside the "customername"

Comment: [Responsive Way](http://jsfiddle.net/cgj20zqq)

Comment: easieast way may be to add `line-height` to customername if there's just going to be a single line. in your example something like `line-height: 2.9;`

Comment: @magreenberg Without extra `div`, can't we do that? This would be maintenance issue. I need to modify every `div` element in the `form`

Comment: @overexchange Of course you can, just apply the styles to the elements them selves instead of the extra div. I just did that since it was quickest in my head.

Comment: @magreenberg Looks good. you already said `top:50%`. Is this not redundant to say `translatey(-50%)`?

Comment: with top:50% you move the origin of your div (the top part) to the center of the container... with translatey(-50%) you move up half the div height over its own axis. so the result is a perfect centered element

Comment: @overexchange Look at what Alvaro said. They work in conjunction to create the effect.

Comment: @magreenberg I wish you could provide this as an answer, instead of a comment. Awesome. I checked it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4geph4d9/2/). Thank you so much

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez For using `top`, I need `position` property. Does element need to have `position` property to use `translateY()`?

Comment: Nope. translate works with any position

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez you mean element with `position:static`(default) would also works.

Comment: @overexchange [Join me in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96048/magreenberg)

Answer (score 2):

Modified your code a little to have your elements vertically aligned as suggested.

However I do advice you to think about your element positioning better, this form will likely not be good in terms of responsive behavior and layout.

```css
.shoppingform {
  width: 400px;
  height: 800px;
  background: #7CB9E8;
  /* url(some img)*/
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
.customername {
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: black;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 10px 2px 5px 5px;
  background: #B284BE;
  width: 90%;
  border-radius: 5px;  
}
.customername {
  height: 5%;
}
.customername {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.shoppingform > div > input {
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 60%;
}
.formlabel {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<form class="shoppingform" action="someaction.php" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Step1: Your details
  <br/>
  <div class="customername">
    <label class="formlabel">Name:</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.shoppingform {
  width: 400px;
  height: 800px;
  background: #7CB9E8;
  padding-left: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-top: 47.5%;
}
.customername {
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: black;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 10px 2px 5px 5px;
  background: #B284BE;
  width: 90%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 5%;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.shoppingform > div > input {
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 60%;
}
.formlabel {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<form class="shoppingform" action="someaction.php" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Step1: Your details
  <br>
  <div class="customername">
    <label class="formlabel">Name:</label>
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</form>
```